# iOS UIButton can't click in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I had search some post before. But I can't try out the correct result.

I generate more button and add the view in the UIScrollView.

I had set autolayout in storybaord about the view and scrollview.

But the Button click are not listener. I don't know why.

I had set

```
 _sclVW.delaysContentTouches = NO;
[_sclVW setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
_sclVW.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

But the button still can't click.

My code is below:

```
     _sclVW.delegate = self;

    _sclVW.delaysContentTouches = NO;
    [_sclVW setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    _sclVW.userInteractionEnabled = YES;


    int btnWidth = 80,btnHigh=50;
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 50 ; i++ )
    {

        UIButton *button  =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnSendTag:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.tag = i;
        button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
        button.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        button.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [button setEnabled:YES];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];

        if( i < 3)
        {
            button.frame = CGRectMake( i *(btnWidth +  20),  0 , 80,50 );
        }
        else
        {
            button.frame = CGRectMake( (i%3) *(btnWidth +  20), (i/3) *(btnHigh + 20)  , 80,50 );

        }
        [_contentVW addSubview:button];

    }
}

-(void) btnSendTag:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"btn click:%li",(long)sender.tag);
}
```

Have anyone know how to resolve the problem?

thank you very much.

I had post my simple test project in [github(this code).](https://github.com/dickfalaDeveloper/ScrollViewBtnTest.git)

Comment: Button adding to scrollview?

Comment: can you please check your OS Version if its 7.1?i found some issues in uicollectionview/UIScrollView that button touch not working in this scenario.

Comment: thank you, you can refer @Kampai answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your issue from sample project. Issue here is height and width of  `contentVW` in Storyboard is `0`. So that subview (buttons) of this view can not be interact with user.

Look at the picture below:

[image]

Here you can see that subview of `UIScrollView` has value `0` for `width` and `height`.

So change `width` and `height` of view same like scrollview and than you can able to tap on these buttons.

[image]

Comment: Thank you,@Kampai. You are right, the contentView not set value, so it's not work. thank you.